# How do I fix compiler error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or 'attribute' before '{' token|"?

Tags: c, date-arithmetic

I am trying to build a code to calculate capacitance reactance in a simple series capacitive reactor for my electronics class. The purpose of the code is irrelevant, as the problem is that I am doing something very wrong and need help with my C skills. This is the formula should you need it:

[image: Formula for Capacitance]

**Here is my code:**
(excluding the headers as they cause format errors in the html of the post)

```
const float pi = 3.145962;

float xc(float frequency, float capacitance)





int main()
{

float capreac;
 float valueofc ()
 float valueoff ()
   capreac = xc(f;c;)
}


float xc(float frequncy, float capaitance);
{
    float answer;
    answer = (1/(2*pi*capacitance*frequency));
     return(answer);


}
```

My IDE is CodeBlocks, which is what my class is using.

It refuses to run, stating "|13|error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '**attribute**' before '{' token|" at the "float xc" line and "|6|error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition|" at the defining line of xc.

Any hope for this newb?

Comment: [Learn a little bit about `C`](http://www.learn-c.org/), because you have some glaring syntax errors and logical issues throughout your code.

Comment: semicolons are messed-up.

Comment: ... and what is `xc(f;c;)` ?

Comment: Remove the semicolon between the `)` and `{` in the function definition and move it after the function declaration.

Comment: You don't have an actual question.

Comment: I am having major issues, as I am in first year of C, and even after applying changes to my code am having errors.

Comment: That's a very bad approximation of `pi`. I suggest that you `#include <math.h>` and use `M_PI` instead of your own definition.

Comment: That's what I did initially, however this is code I received from my instructor, he preferred us to declare pi in this fashion :(

Comment: Ok, then at least fire up your calculator and get the correct value for pi.

Comment: Except your `pi` is off by the 3rd decimal place. OTOH it starts with 3.14159265358979323846... Also @user3386109 `M_PI` is not part of the C standard, so may not be always present.

Comment: I swear I copied the code he demonstrated... And yet I'm still so wrong... gd it. Thank you guys.

Comment: I had no idea what to call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You need a semicolon and the end of your prototype:

`float xc(float frequency, float capacitance);`

2) Variable declarations don't have "()"

```
float f;
float c;
```

3) arguments are separated by commas: `capreac = xc(f, c);`

4) argument names should match variable names:

```
float xc(float frequency, float capacitance);
{
  float answer;
  answer = (1.0/(2.0*pi*capacitance*frequency));
  ...
```

Comment: See my comment above - delete the semicolon you have between `)` and `{` in the function definition.

Comment: Looking back, I am not even mad that I got so many downvotes for this!

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
typedef long double ldouble; 
ldouble xc(ldouble f, ldouble C){ return 1/(2*M_PIl*f*C);}
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  ldouble f, C, answer;

  puts("Enter f:");
  scanf("%Lf", &f);
  puts("Enter C:");
  scanf("%Lf", &C);
  answer = xc(f, C);
  printf("Xc=%Lf\n", answer);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why ldouble and not float?

Comment: Floats are rather imprecise. You're better off with double at the very least.

Comment: @PSkocik:  Since you're going for precision, can you fix the definition of PI so it's actually correct?  Kind of silly to have a precise wrong answer.

Comment: M_PIl from math.h it is.:)

Comment: Thank you for your help m8. I was lost. but now i C.